# How to reuse a frozen previously learned subgraph in new computation graphs

Tags: tensorflow

I have build an autoencoder which is trained using the Dataset API. The architecture is depicted on this tensorboard schema :

[image: Autoencoder data flow diagram]

I would like to reuse only the encoder part in an other learning task so I have attempted to freeze the graph using

```python
g = tf.graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(sess, sess.graph_def, ["AEC/encoded"])
g = tf.graph_util.extract_sub_graph(g, ["AEC/encoded"])
g = tf.graph_util.remove_training_nodes(g, protected_nodes=["AEC/input", "AEC/encoded"])
with open(str(Path(params.encoder_export_dir)/"encoder.pb"), "wb") as f:
    f.write(g.SerializeToString())
```

and then trying to import it in my other code using

```python
encoder_input = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2049])
gd = tf.GraphDef()
with open('./path/to/encoder.pb', 'rb') as f:
    gd.ParseFromString(f.read())
[out] = tf.import_graph_def(gd,
                            input_map={"AEC/input" : encoder_input},
                            return_elements=['AEC/encoded'],
                            name=''
                           )
```

but when running the `out` tensor with feeding something in `encoder_input` I get `None` as result

I've tried to visualize the exported graph in tensorboard

[image: Exported model dataflow diagram]

and it seems that the shape of the tensors as disappeared.

So my question is how can I export my encoder in a way which allows me to use it as a "black box" in an other piece of code ?

**EDIT :**

I have implemented my model using placeholder instead of Dataset iterator get_next tensors and the lack of dimension stays the same except for the input node (corresponding to the placeholder) which stores its shape in its attributes.

**Edit 2 :**

Following the advice in [this issue report](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/3903) I added the shape information when exporting my graph using

```python
g = tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def(add_shapes=True)
```

and now see the shape information on the tensorboard schema, but the computation still returns `None`

Comment: Have you been able to prune off the Dataset Iterator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the problem was due to a syntax mistake : instead of using

```
[out] = tf.import_graph_def(gd,
                        input_map={"AEC/input" : encoder_input},
                        return_elements=['AEC/encoded'],
                        name=''
                       )
```

where `AEC/encoded` in `return_elements` is an operation, the correct way is to ask tensorflow for the output of this operation with `AEC/encoded:0`